# OrientDB studio login background image replace?

Tags: orientdb

OK, I'll admit I'm trying to do a stupid OrientDB trick to amaze and annoy my fellow coders, but is there any way to change the background image for the studio login page?  That picture of the ocean is pretty, but what if I want to have something else come up?  Is that image accessible in the OrientDB code someplace (where I haven't found it yet)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is on OrientDB's GitHub:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio/blob/master/app/img/sunrise-beach.jpg

Comment: Yup, that's the one that I'm trying to replace.  It's good to know the exact name of the file.  I just realized that my problem is that I'm running OrientDB in docker and need to gain access to the image through it.  So this is not a simple matter of finding the path to the image file after all.  Thanks for the reply.